# Decision Tree clarification

Tags: binary-tree, decision-tree

I just want to ask/clarify if decision trees are essentially binary trees where each node is a boolean, and it continues down until a desired result is reached?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. Some nodes may share children which is not the case in Binary trees. However, the essence of the decision tree is what you mentioned.

It's a tree where based on the probability of an outcome you move down the graph until you hit an outcome.

See [Wikipedia's page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) on desicion trees for more info.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Ares, not all decision trees are binary (they can be "n-ary") although most implementation I have seen are binary trees.

For instance if you have a color variable (i.e. categorical) that can take three values : `red`, `blue` or `green`; you might want to split in three directly at a node instead of splitting in two and then again in two (or more).
The choice between binary and "n-ary" will usually depends on your data. I suspect that most people use binary trees anyway because it is relatively easier to implement and more flexible.

Then as you said the tree is developed until the desired outcome is reached. Decision Tree suffers major drawbacks such as overfitting and there exist many different ways to tackle this issue (pruning, boosting, etc.) but this is beyond the scope of the question/answer.

I recommend to have a look at this great visualization that explains well the decision tree : http://www.r2d3.us/visual-intro-to-machine-learning-part-1/

Will be happy to give more details about decision tree